# Why data bind template is not working on 2.2 or greater?

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I was studying about Knockout.js and how it works with Magento 2.

Then I reached the topic: template integration, in the first sample of it I'm presented to this notation:

```
<div data-bind="template:'Namespace_Module/sample'"></div>
```

Which will try to render the template located at:

```
app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/web/template/sample.html
```

It's working in Magento versions equals/lower than 2.1.

In greater versions it's throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return 'Namespace_Module/sample' }"
Message: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at RemoteTemplateEngine.makeTemplateSource (engine.js:55)
    at RemoteTemplateEngine.renderTemplate (engine.js:116)
    at executeTemplate (knockout.js:4886)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhen (knockout.js:4950)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
    at Object.ko.renderTemplate (knockout.js:4942)
    at update (knockout.js:5080)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3004)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
```

I was trying to understand why it's happening looking for the change in github, but it's not clear to me:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d99043c097816388b2aeec1c23e10bf15e064b28#diff-9ec27f11f8253078a99c9d1e979a07f3

Now it requires a bindingContext (which contain the name attribute requested in exception) but I don't know how it's initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data-bind to this:

```
<div data-bind="template:{ name : 'Namespace_Module/sample' }"></div>
```

It should work like that!

Comment: Thanks, Mkougiouris! But It also doesn't work. It just changed the error msg to: `Unable to process binding "template: function(){return { name:'Namespace_Module/sample'} }"`

Comment: Paste more of the exception message if you can, so that we can inspect it further down the stack